# Receive emails to configured domain in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I have to create email receiver,sender to my systems. Senario is like this,

**Login user will configure his email server settings to my system,I can be gmail,yahoo or any other domain.then user should be able to send & receive emails through the system.**

it's like outlook or http://webmail.com/ but no need that advance.. just need simply send and receive email using configured mail server.

I search internet so much couldn't find any helpful article. :(

can anyone help me on this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not that simple..

Steps to follow to achieve your requirement

**1.** First you need figure it out for whichever email domains you can support like gmail,outlook,hotmail..

**2.** For each domain you need to create a webhook, based on user(example:if you have 2 gmail id configured then there will be 2 web-hook created for gmail)

**3.** If you create webhook it sends you an email to your api, when user got new email.

**4.** You need to store that in your db, and then you can show it in your application

Hope this helps:)